# How to detect slider open in Xperia Play

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, sony

i am developing a game on xperia play. Can any one tell me how to detect Slider open for the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are more sophisticated solutions, but you can add to your activity   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" in manifest.

And handle opening with onConfigurationChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

Check logcat. If any broadcast fired when slider opened, you might want to use a broadcast receiver. Look [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) for broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

To detect the gamepad slide in/out for Xperia PLAY, please use the following configuration constant: NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_*

For more information about configuration, please visit:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html